# How to check if function will run or is available?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function like this :

```
$.myFunction
```

Depending on version a user may have of the .js file where the function resides the function may not be called successfully since it does not exist. If this function does not run I just want to ignore any errors that are thrown and continue execution. One workaround is to wrap the function in a try/catch :

```
try {
$.myFunction
}
catch(e){
}
```

But it seems bad practice to me to use a try/catch in this way. Is there jQuery/javascript method to check if a function exists before running it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing you're calling the function as

```
$.myFunction();
```

You may test

```
if ($.myFunction) {
```

But it's a little strange to have to do that on a library. Aren't you including it yourself ? To try to do with any version of a lib just as if it was complete seems dangerous.

Comment: its included in an .js file that resides on seperate server and due to security some users may not have access. So if a user does not have access I just want the function to not run.

Answer (score 1):

To check before calling it:

```
typeof $.myFunction == 'function' && $.myFunction();
```

It's also typical to conditionally declare the function:

```
$.myFunction = $.myFunction || function () { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function: [`$.isFunction`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/):

```
if($.isFunction($.myFunction)) {
    // it exists and it is function
}
```